# How to mysql select second attachment from all wp users

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select

What i have so far is the following query, which gives me the post id of the first attachment of each user.

```
    $sql = "
        SELECT ID, post_author, post_title, post_type 
        FROM wp_posts 
        WHERE post_author > '1' AND post_type = 'attachment' 
        GROUP BY post_author 
        ORDER BY ID;";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) OR die(mysqli_error($link));

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $USERID = $row['post_author'];
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $TITLE = $row['post_title'];

    $sql2 = "UPDATE alle 
    SET `image0` = '$ID'
    WHERE `Userid` = '$USERID';";

    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql2)){
    echo "Image0 inserted successfully.";
    } else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql2. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    }
    echo "finished";
    mysqli_close($link);
```

What I need now is to check, if the user has a second attachment and if so, list the post ids of the second attachment to put them in a non wordpress table. I am trying since hours, but i am stuck.

Comment: What results are you getting, @Harry666 ? Is there an error message? Or are you just getting multiple results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may solve your problem :

Just include count(*) in your query to get number of attachments for given author

```
SELECT ID, post_author, post_title, post_type, count(*) AS number_of_attachments 
FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author > '1' AND post_type = 'attachment' 
GROUP BY post_author 
ORDER BY ID
```

If you also need post ids of all attachments you can use GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT ID, post_author, post_title, post_type, count(*) AS number_of_attachments, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) AS all_post_ids 
FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author > '1' AND post_type = 'attachment' 
GROUP BY post_author 
ORDER BY ID
```

Here column all_post_ids will contain comma separated IDs of each post of type attachment for given post_author